# common techniques for styling buttons in react native?

Tags: react-native

What are some common techniques for styling buttons in RN?  For example, what if I want to display my button with the following attributes:

color:red
height:50

Also, what if I want to display Button text with sentence casing?  For example, "Login with Email"?  Looks like the title attribute of a button displays the title text in all caps and I'm not sure how I can change that?

Or is the general practice that, when a developer wants to customize a button like this, some type of custom structure composed of a View and TouchableOpacity should generally be used?

Answer (score 0):

React Native Button by itself does not give many options to customize.You can try out various `Touchable*` and make button from scratch in more generic fashion.

It may look something like this

```
const Button=(props)=>(
  <TouchableOpacity>
   <View style={[styles.button,props.overrideStyles]}>
     <Text style={[styles.buttonText,props.overrideTextStyle]}>{props.title}</Text>
   </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>
)

const style=StyleSheet.create({
  button:{height:50},
  buttonText:{textTransform:'capitalize',color:'red'}
})
```